# Susy: fluid columns with fixed gutters?

Tags: susy-compass

I'm trying to build a 12 column grid with fluid columns and fixed gutters. Columns would change width as the window resizes, but the gutters would remain constant. Basically, percentage for columns, ems for gutters.

Is this possible with Susy?

Comment: Sorry, no, it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, Eric. And thanks for sharing Susy with the world.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the padding as your gutter and would allow you to have a fixed "spacing" while keeping the fluid nature of the grid.
This would however force you to add extra markup if you need backgrounds that doesnt extend to the "gutter" area.