# Using Susy Next How Do I Create A Grid With Fluid Columns With Fixed Gutters

Tags: grid, sass, susy-compass

**How do I set up a grid with fluid columns and fixed gutters using Susy Next?**

It looks like `Gutter Position` is the way to go, offering two settings that use padding for the gutters [See Docs](http://susy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#gutter-position):

> inside
>   Gutters are added as padding on both sides of a layout
>   element, and are not removed at the edges of the grid.
>
> inside-static
>   Gutters are added as static padding on both sides of
>   a layout element, even in a fluid layout context, and are not removed
>   at the edges of the grid.

However, I've had no success using it. There is no mention of how it should be used in the Docs so far as I can see, so it seemed logical that the following would work:

```
$default-layout: (
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  columns: 12,
  container: rem-calc(1000),
  gutter-position: inside-static, // Same with `static`
  gutters: rem-calc(20)
);
```

However this causes an error as soon as `@include span()` is used:

```
Invalid null operation: "12 times null".
```

I've tried adding an explicit column-width:

```
  column-width: 8.333333333%,
```

I am aware there are mixins for adding prefixed and suffixed padding manually, but I want this as a global setting which applies to all spans.

Essentially I'm after the equivalent of this (but with 12 columns):

```
.wrapper
{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

.column
{
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Codepen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dCuFn)

Note: I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619637/susy-fluid-columns-with-fixed-gutters?rq=1), but it references Susy 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [helpful Issue](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/347) on Susy's Github, linking to a [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7da95c41fff076dd7266) containing an example of what I'm after.

The following works for me:

```
$gutter-width: rem-calc(10);
$pointless-column-width: rem-calc(1);

// Default layout
$default-layout: (
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  columns: 12,
  container: rem-calc(1000),
  gutter-position: inside-static,
  column-width: $pointless-column-width,
  gutters: $gutter-width/$pointless-column-width
);

$susy: $default-layout;
```

I don't understand why a column width needs to be set, and the actual value of it seems to have no effect at all (as long as it isn't null or zero). It just needs to be present.

More in this [Github issue](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/368) I raised including a [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/1dd8fd59038851722334).

Comment: The value does in fact have an effect, if you look closely — you have just written variables in such a way that the effect is hidden from you. The `column-width` is the basic unit of math that Susy uses, and the `gutters` setting is always a ratio *in relation to that value*. But I agree, it's not ideal. That's because `inside-static` was added late in the game. This is something I want to clean up for Susy 3.